# Shell script and sudo

Tags: unix, shell

In my shell script i have the following line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/somedir
```

Say im logged in as user mike. I need to execute the shell script as root, so i run it as sudo filename.sh, so $USER becomes root in my path in that case.

I want it to be that of the user running the script, i.e. mike instead of root. Is there a way to achieve this?

Thank You

Answer (score 5):

Do you *have* to use `/home/$USER`, or will `$HOME` do the trick? IIRC, `sudo` doesn't override the value of `$HOME`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$SUDO_USER` (if you insist on using `$USER` directly, set its value as shown):

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$SUDO_USER" != "" ]; then
  USER=$SUDO_USER;
fi

export PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/somedir
```

Or cheat using `$USER` as the first parameter to the script (error checking is an exercise for the reader):

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
USER=$1

export PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/somedir
```

Then:

```
$ sudo ./script.sh $USER
```

Or use `$HOME`, as suggested by Chris Jester-Young. You could use bash to remove the "/home/" prefix, but that would be an ugly hack.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use `su` instead of `sudo`, you can do

```
su -cp filename.sh
```

to execute the command while preserving your environment.

Comment: su? That's yuck, because it requires a root password instead of your own password.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using $UID, which should still be set to the user's real ID number and retrieving their name out of the password database based on that.

Comment: Why not go whole hog and suggest getting the home directory out of the password database? HOME=$(getent passwd $SUDO_UID | cut -d: -f6)

Comment: Yes; then using $HOME seems simpler :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to preserve environnement, you can use the -E option of sudo. But it needs some configuration and security politics ... That applies if the $HOME solution proposed by Chris JY does not apply as it is simpler.

my 2 cents

Answer (score 0):

*sudo* is different form "root" user. If any user has sudo privileges, that means he has the admin rights that are available with the user "root". That is, using *sudo* doesn't change the user to root.